# closing and opening live-server for an app deletes my local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I wrote some basic 'To-do' app in JavaScript and HTML, for some reason local storage is deleting after I close and re-open the live-server in terminal.
when i refresh or even close browser and re opens it, everything works just fine.

just when I close the live-server and re opens it and enters to the browser app, all local storage gone and i start fresh (which is only an array of objects called 'todos')

While using the app the local storage items are created perfectly and saved perfectly.

this is how I wrote my getSavedTodos (from local storage) and the saveToStorage functions:

```
// Fetch existing todos from localStorage
const getSavedTodos= () => {
    const todosJSON= localStorage.getItem('todos')
    if(todosJSON !== null)
    {
        return (JSON.parse(todosJSON))        
    }
    else
    {
        return []
    }
}



//save todos to storage
const saveDataToStorage= (todos) =>
{
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos))
    
}
```

what am I missing?

this is my terminal

```
na:~/Desktop/js/apps$ live-server todo-app
http://0.0.0.0:8080 is already in use. Trying another port.
Ready for changes
Serving "todo-app" at http://127.0.0.1:41709
GET /favicon.ico 404 1.473 ms - 150
^C
na:~/Desktop/js/apps$ live-server todo-app
http://0.0.0.0:8080 is already in use. Trying another port.
Ready for changes
Serving "todo-app" at http://127.0.0.1:38307
GET /favicon.ico 404 2.197 ms - 150
Change detected todo-app/todo-functions.js
```

The port that is taken (8080) is another app im working on.

Thank you very much!

Comment: how do you start the server? localStorage is unique per origin, make sure your server is always running on same address.

Comment: @yash I will add my terminal to the question, so if my port is different this is the reason why? how I make sure it`ll go back to same port if this is the problem?

Comment: added it in answer

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage is unique per origin. You have to make sure the server always run on same port.

You can close the app running on 8080. Or simple run the app on another port:

```
live-server todo-app --port=8081
```